# NestJS SSE with simple Subject

Tags: nestjs, server-sent-events

I'm trying to create a notification using Server Sent Events in NestJS.
What I'm trying to do is expose 2 end points
`/room` -> POST method to create a room
`/room` -> SSE to send notification(s) when a new room is added.

In RoomsService,
I have a simple array that holds rooms created by the user.
And an rxjs Subject, that publishes a newly added room.

```
// RoomsService.ts

@Injectable()
export class RoomsService {
  private rooms: Room[] = [];
  private _rooms$: Subject<Room> = new Subject<Room>();

  public get rooms$(): Observable<Room> {
    return this._rooms$.asObservable();
  }

  createRoom(roomDto: CreateRoomDto): Room {
    const room: Room = {
      title: roomDto.title,
      creator: {
        id: v4(),
        name: roomDto.creator,
      },
      createdAt: new Date(Date.now()),
      updatedAt: new Date(Date.now()),
      id: v4(),
    };

    this.rooms.push(room);
    this._rooms$.next(room);
    return room;
  }

  getRoom(id: string): Room | undefined {
    console.log(this.rooms);
    return this.rooms.find((room) => room.id === id);
  }
}
```

And then in RoomsController

```
// RoomsController.ts

@Controller('rooms')
export class RoomsController {
  constructor(
    private roomsService: RoomsService,
    private eventEmitter: EventEmitter2,
  ) {}
  @Post()
  createRoom(@Body() body: CreateRoomDto): Room {
    return this.roomsService.createRoom(body);
  }

  @Get(':id')
  getRoom(@Param('id') id: string): Room {
    const room = this.roomsService.getRoom(id);
    if (!room) {
      throw new HttpException('Room Not Found', HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }

    return room;
  }

  @Sse('/notif')
  notif(): Observable<Room> {
    return this.roomsService.rooms$.pipe(map((room) => room));
  }
}
```

But for some reason the SSE doesn't publish the newly created room to the client.
The POST endpoint works correctly, but the subject's next value is not emitted.
What could be the issue?

PS: I was able to get this working with the EventEmitter. Just wondering if this could be done without using EventEmitter and with just Subject.